# How to model a mixer with several input channels in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

So far I cannot find a corresponding element in Spring Integration for a mixer that should have several inbound channels.  For example an aggregator still has only one inbound channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a single component for that; you can configure multiple service-activators (or outbound-channel-adapters if the method returns void) that reference the same bean/method.

**EDIT**

You could also use `<bridge/>` elements to bridge multiple channels to a single one.

**EDIT2**

```
<int:bridge input-channel = "bar" output-channel="multi" />
<int:bridge input-channel = "foo" output-channel="multi" />
...
<int:bridge input-channel = "zul" output-channel="multi" />

<some-multi-input-component input-channel="multi" />
```

Comment: Gary, I remember that I found one element that allowed to configure additional input channels besides the default one - or I am not right?

Comment: No; there is no such component; you could also use bridges.

Comment: Maybe, you can give an example